# SCSS/SASS - using BEM with SASS and atributes

Tags: css, sass

I'm using BEM to name my class names, example: .accordion, .accordion__title, .accordion__item__content.

For that I created the following mixin:

```
@mixin child_el($element) {

        &__#{$element} {
        @content;
      }
    }
```

It is working very well, but I have an issue when I need to add also attributes:

```
.accordion {
  display: block;
  @include child_el(item) {
    &[state=true] {
    @include child_el(content) {
      display: block;
    }
  }
}
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve:

```
.accordion[state=true] .accordion__item {
 display: block;
}
```

The parent is read as being &[state=true] instead of .accordion

Comment: Is there any reason why you can't use the standard `&[state=true] &__item` syntax? It's been supported for quite some time.

Comment: actually the mixin does this; but how I solve the nesting, can you give me an example to what I'm try to achieve using &

Comment: I added an answer, if I understood correctly what you wanted!

Comment: thanks, very simple; I was so focused on nesting I didn't see it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can rewrite this without the mixin:

```
.accordion {
  display: block;

  &[state=true] &__item {
    display: block;
  }
}
```

The output CSS will be:

```
.accordion {
  display: block;
}

.accordion[state=true] .accordion__item {
  display: block;
}
```